# Are there some websites for self-learning of advanced mathematics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, soft-question, education, mathematics, resource-recommendations

Are there some websites for self-learining of advanced mathematics?
For example there is perimeter scholars for self study of theoretical physics, but I haven't found some good websites providing lecture videos of mathematics
For example, some great lecture vedios of differential geometry, Lie group , Lie algebra, algebraic topology, partial differential equations and so on.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://mathoverflow.net/q/151349/13917

Comment: Cross-posted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/601132/11127

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/54430/13917